# how to push an object to an array within an object with PHP

Tags: php, object, multidimensional-array

I am learning how to use objects and arrays in php. I formerly had an array of categories and an array of objects organized by category in php:

```
public function live_scenarios_by_category(){
  $scenario_list = $this->scenarios_model->get_scenario_data();
  if ($scenario_list){
    $categories = array();
    $scenarios_by_category = array();
    $curCatIndex = -1;
    $curCatName = NULL;
    foreach ($scenario_list as $i=>$scenario){
      $category_name = $scenario['t3'];
      if ($curCatName != $category_name){
        $curCatIndex+=1;
        $categories[$curCatIndex] = $category_name;
        $curCatName = $category_name;
      }
      $scenarios_by_category[$curCatIndex][] = $scenario;
    }
    $data['categories'] = $categories;
    $data['scenarios_by_category'] = $scenarios_by_category;
    $this->load->view('data/json_scenarios', $data);
  }
}
```

I could then successfully output either the categories or the scenarios_by_category:

```
echo json_encode($categories);
```

or

```
echo json_encode($scenarios_by_category);
```

But what I want is for the "categories" array to become an array of objects (scenarios) organized by each category, of the form:

```
[{name: "cat1", children: [{name: "scenario1"},{name: "scenario2"}...]}{name:"cat2", children: [...]}];
```

I tried modifying the code as follows:

```
public function live_scenarios_by_category(){
  $scenario_list = $this->scenarios_model->get_scenario_data();
  if ($scenario_list){
    $categories = array();
    $scenarios_by_category = array();
    $curCatIndex = -1;
    $curCatName = NULL;
    foreach ($scenario_list as $i=>$scenario){
      $category_name = $scenario['t3'];
      if ($curCatName != $category_name){
        $curCatIndex+=1;
        //$categories[$curCatIndex] = $category_name;
        $cat_obj = new stdClass;
        $cat_obj->name = $category_name;
        $cat_obj->children = array();
        $categories[$curCatIndex] = $cat_obj;
        $curCatName = $category_name;
      }
      array_push($categories[$curCatIndex]['children'],$scenario);
      //$categories[$curCatIndex]['children'][] = $scenario;
    }
    $data['categories'] = $categories;
    //  $data['scenarios_by_category'] = $scenarios_by_category;
    $this->load->view('data/json_scenarios', $data);
  }
}
```

But I get the error

```
Cannot use object of type stdClass as array
```

in the line:

```
array_push($categories[$curCatIndex]['children'],$scenario);
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access objects in php use `->` you are using `[]` which is an array

Try changing this

```
array_push($categories[$curCatIndex]['children'],$scenario);
```

to

```
array_push($categories[$curCatIndex]->children,$scenario);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have an associate array, you can convert into Object bellow:

> Associate Array

```
$associateArray = array(
                'name'          => 'Beef',
                'quantity'      => 1,
                'unit'          => 'ks',
                'unit_price'    => 120
        );
```

> Convert Associated Array to Json Object

```
$JsonObject = json_encode($associateArray);
```

> Convert Json Object to Json PHP (Object in PHP)

```
$JsonPhpObject = json_decode($JsonObject);
echo $JsonPhpObject->name;
```

Comment: And: `$object = (object) $array;` was just too long of a code.

Comment: Good Idea, it is another solution!